# "Billeted" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kio estas la E-a vorto "billeted" (English), kiel: "the soldiers were billeted in the farmer's house".

1. "loĝigitaj" eblas sed tiu vorto povas havi plurajn aliajn signifojn
2. "loĝasignitaj" estas pli preciza sed tiu vorto ne troviĝas en kaj PIV kaj Tekstaro
3. "soltatloĝitaj" estas mia preferata vorto... sed ĝi ne estas E-a vorto

Kion vi pensas? Dankon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loĝigi` estas tute trafa. Ĝi signifas: *havigi loĝejon al iu*.

```
La soldatoj estis loĝigitaj en ..
```

En tiu specifa situacio, vi povas klarigi kia estis tiu loĝigo, ekzemple per mencio de la aŭtoritato, kiu decidis tion.

```
La soldatoj estis loĝigitaj de la estraro en ...
```

Pri aliaj ebloj, se la kunmetaĵo kompreneblas, uzu ĝin, neniu vortaro havos ĉiun eblan kunmetaĵon.

Answer (score 1):

*to billet* = *[kantonmenti](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kanton1.html#kanton1.0i.MIL)*
*billeted* = *kantonmentita*

Ekzistas ankaŭ *kvartiri* ([de] *einquartieren*), kio pli plaĉus al germanlingvano, tamen en Reta Vortaro ĝi  kondukis al *kantonmenti*.

Kompreneble la termino ne sekvas la principon de simpleco, do taŭgas precipe por progresita teksto.

---

***Post komentoj***

Specifa termino estas evitebla per duvorta traduko.

> to billet = asigni loĝejon/restejon (precipe mil.).

Pro tio ke *loĝejo* estas tro nespecifa, mi proponas *restejo*, germane *Quartier*. En la senco de dormoloko kaj pli.

Comment: Laŭ mi tiu estas unu el tiuj radikoj tute evitendaj. Ĝi estas longega, neoficiala kaj ĝene nurŝajne analizebla.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani _kantonmento_ mi konas en la nederlanda, probable francdevena. _kvartiri_ certe aspektas germanismo. Por fakaj terminoj mi pli akceptas neologismon (ol vi). Sistema traduko - kia via - certe pli taŭgas por pontolingvo. Tamen en verko militisma termino povas aldoni specifan etoson. _billeted_ estus same evitinda eble. Tamen vi tute pravas. Dankon pro la indiko pri la neoficialeco, kaj ankaŭ estas rara termino.

Comment: Mi tute samopinias kun Eduardo. Kiam oni intencas lanĉi novan radikon, demandu vin, kiom da derivaĵoj vi povas krei de tiu radiko. Se la nombro estas tre malalta, ne indas lanĉi la radikon. "Loĝigi" estas klara kaj logika.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas: por akcenti: _La soldatoj estis asignitaj loĝejon en ..._ Mi fakte samopinias, tamen samrajtigas _kantonmenti_. Vorto kiel _leŭtenanto_ havas sian rajton. En militisma vortaro _kantonmenti_ same. La alternativo estus en esperanta angla vortaro aldoni _loĝigita (mil.) = billeted_. Eduardo ankaŭ kritikas la elekton de la radiko mem,. Tute prave, ekz. la germana _einquartieren_ povas esti uzata pli ofte, kaj ankaŭ havas pli da uzeblo: _Quartier_ signifas _loloĝej(et)o_. **Mi principe donis la respondon pro la manko de vortetoj kiel _billet_ kaj _Quartier_ en tradukvortaroj.**

Comment: Mia antaŭa komento estas senkohera. Plej bone estas **_to billet_ = _asigni loĝejon/restejon_ (precipe mil.).** Do duvorta traduko.